# Yasnippet and pabbrev working together in Emacs

Tags: emacs, pabbrev

I am trying to get the yasnippet and pabbrev packages working together with emacs, but I cannot seem to get any love.  How can I get them to play nicely together?

The crux of the problem is that pabbrev and yasnippet are binding to the tab keys.  Both packages seem to do this fallback when a match isn't found, but they don't fall back properly.

I am currently using Emacs W32 (the last emacs 22 release).  yasnippet is byte compiled, but pabbrev is not.

Edit:  Thus far neither tabkey2 nor hippie expand work out of the box, which is why I have yet to mark either solution as a correct answer.  I'm hacking away at tabkey2 to make it work though.

Comment: More data needed.  Are you byte-compiling?

Comment: How are they "not playing nicely" can you be more concrete?

Comment: Hahha.  Me = lame.  Question is updated.

Comment: did you get it working?  Can you post what you did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [tabkey2.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/tabkey2.el).  It looks like it addresses the problem you're having.

Answer (score 4):

I use [hippie-expand](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/hippie-exp-ext.el) to manage  tab expansion packages.

The following code will try each package in order to expand your tab key press:

```
(require 'hippie-exp)

(setq hippie-expand-try-functions-list
      '(yas/hippie-try-expand
        try-expand-dabbrev
        try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers
        try-expand-dabbrev-from-kill
        try-complete-file-name
        try-complete-lisp-symbol))
```

Note: hippie-expand will probably not work with pabbrev, because pabbrev is an emacs minor mode.